# Pixel colors different at the border

Tags: color, cs6, borders

What brush or what configuration should I do to avoid different color at the border when using the brush tool?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To avoid this don't use the **Brush Tool** because has soft borders by default, even with 100% hardness. Use the **Pencil Tool** instead.

[image: BRUSH/PENCIL]